# Android, How to get context in C2DMReceiver constructor?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, android-context

I have a C2DM receiver class that initialises the C2DM sender email in the constructor.
The thing is, I need to get the senders email from a resource string and therefore I need to get the context in the constructor for the receiver

The receiver looks like this

```
public class C2DMReceiver extends C2DMBaseReceiver {

    public C2DMReceiver() {
        super(AppConstants.getC2DMSender(this)); // How do I get the context here?
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
            throws java.io.IOException { ...
```

The relevant code on the C2DMBaseReceiver

```
public abstract class C2DMBaseReceiver extends IntentService {
...
    private final String senderId;

    /**
     * The C2DMReceiver class must create a no-arg constructor and pass the 
     * sender id to be used for registration.
     */
    public C2DMBaseReceiver(String senderId) {
        // senderId is used as base name for threads, etc.
        super(senderId);
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }
...
```

It's not really relevant to the question but for background purposes the reason for needing this is that the code is in a library project that is used in many android projects each of which has it's own sender's email address defined in a resource file. The AppConstants class has the job of reading the various resource strings and follows on from my accepted answer for a previous question here [Android, Best way to provide app specific constants in a library project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761386/android-best-way-to-provide-app-sepcific-constants-in-a-library-project)

Finally for completeness the AppConstants.getC2DMSender method looks like this

```
public static String getC2DMSender(Context c){
    return c.getResources().getString(uk.co.the_prize_quiz.quiz_template.R.string.c2dm_sender);
}
```

The specific app that users this library has the responsibility of setting the c2dm_sender variable in an xml resource. So in order to get this variable I need the context

```
<item type="string" name="c2dm_sender" format="string">app_specific_registered_c2dm@email_address</item>
```

Because this is set in a resource string the specific app can set this value and the template will use it automatically.

Comment: If you find any complications to get a context in library project, you can copy those files or package into your project and change as you required.

Comment: Wasn't aware that could be done and I might just have to do that but I'd really rather not unless there is no other option. Thanks for the info

Comment: How are you planning on tackling the different packages for the different sender emails? When signing up to C2DM, you need to specify a requested sender email, and the package of your app. The package is used by C2DM to call your C2DMReceiver class (defined in the manifest), are you sure this class will be properly called when you'll be able to correctly set the email in the constructor?

Comment: @marmor the manifest for each specific app sets up the permissions for that app which seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a singleton class to your library. Have a member to hold the senderid and corresponding getter and setter methods...

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   private String mSenderId = nulll; // Your data holder

   protected ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }

   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }

   /* Setter and Getter for the mAppContext member here */
   public void setSender(String sender) {
       mSenderId = sender;
   }

}
```

In your app's activity `ClassicSingleton.getInstance().setSender("SENDER_ID")`

In your C2DM class

```
public C2DMReceiver() {
    super(ClassicSingleton.getInstance().getSender());
}
```

Try to have the app's context as the member instead of senderId. Then you can pull any resource you need I guess.. Let me know.

Comment: I've accepted the answer but I haven't had time to try it, I'll get back to you later and thank you for your perseverance

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the conclusion that this can not be done in the way I was attempting.
I have temporarily solved my problem by creating a new class in each app that descends from the class in the library project and just overriding the constructor in each app.

It's not an idea solution and kind of defeats the point of having a library but at least I can share most of my code.

Comment: I too think it cannot be done the way you wanted. But you can still try -- have a class in the library that holds the data needed for registering to C2DM. Set this data in your activity before registration call. You will have to make static references.

Comment: @userSeven7s I'd love to try this option. if you would care to have a go at answering with a suggested code example of how this could be done I'd be grateful

Answer (score 1):

C2DMBaseReceiver doesn't actually use the senderId unless it needs to retry a registration request.  C2DMBaseReceiver is an object (IntentService) that gets created and destroyed for each operation (register response, message from server, and re-try registration).  As long as you set the senderId before you register, you should be fine.

This seems to work:

```
public class C2DMReceiver extends C2DMBaseReceiver {
    private static String gSenderId = "dummy";

    public C2DMReceiver() {
        super(gSenderId);
    }

    public static void register(Context context, String senderId) {
        gSenderId = senderId;
        C2DMessaging.register(context, senderId);
    }

    ...
}
```

Since you are creating a library that provides C2DM service, you should consider what @fargath said and incorporate the c2dm.jar functions directly in your library.  Then you can customize the interface as needed.  In addition, the c2dm.jar provides an indirection to your library code, then your library code provides an equivalent indirection to the app.  It is a bit of a waste.

The c2dm.jar code is only three short files.  I am writing a library similar to yours and will likely pull the functionality in myself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm reluctant to change the indirection, although I had previously considered this, on the basis of "If it works, don't fix it". I have found a solution that meets my needs very nicely based around my accepted answer only using an Application singleton rather than a custom singleton, which does work very well. You have however provided a lot of food for thought and possibly a much nicer solution. Now I have a working library time constraints mean I need to move on, but the fact that I have a library allows me to refactor when time is available. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
//As C2DMReceiver receiver extends Intent service, rather than passing this , call getApplicationConext 

public class C2DMReceiver extends C2DMBaseReceiver {

public C2DMReceiver() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    super(AppConstants.getC2DMSender(context); // This way you can pass context.
}

@Override
public void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
        throws java.io.IOException { ...
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I get 2 errors stating that Implicit super constructor C2DMBaseReceiver() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor AND Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor, thanks for the reply though

Comment: @jamesw try this `super(AppConstants.getC2DMSender(getApplicationContext()));`

Comment: @userSeven7s Thank's for the suggestion but this gives me an error "Cannot refer to an instance method while explicitly invoking a constructor"